# HDMI freezes on High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, performance, hdmi

Sometimes when I plug my HDMI cable in, the macbook freezes.
It's 15inch retina, early 2013, recently clean installed macOS `High Sierra`.

I've resetted the `NVRAM` and the `SMC`, many times, problem is occasionally there.
And no, I won't replace the HDMI cable as it was working **just fine** with all previous versions of macOS/OSX.

On a quora thread I've read that possibly the `automatic graphics card` switching might be the reason, which can be found in `Settings`/`Energy Saver`. This might make sense, as this issue happens when I take my laptop off my desk (unplug charger and HDMI), and then plug it back in.

Comment: Have you considered that your cable could have gone broken in the mean while? - It seems odd to have such a need to let everyone know that you're not buying a new cable. If a 4$ purchase could save you from a lot of grief, why not? ... That said, I have no indications that cable change is necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exactly same issue.  It started to happen after my upgrade to High Sierra.  I own a Mid 2012 MacBook Pro with Retina display.  I googled a bit and found that this happens mostly to MacBook Pro with Retina owners 2012- or 2013-version.

Resetting NVRAM/PRAM or SMC did not work for me but turning off automatic graphic switching as you suggested worked. I will have to turn it off until Apple got to fix this.